# jQuery expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is a bit silly question, but I still cannot find an answer, perhaps I am searching the keywords are not right.

I hope someone could correct my js expression.

```
var id = idname;
$('#' + id).hide();
```

('#' + id) expression has error from console, I'd like to have $('#***variable***') what is the right expression `$('"#'+xerocon2013'"').`

Thanks for someone could put me up

Update,

Sorry guys, I have dollar sign. 
the error is

> unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLDivElement]

I tested yesterday was fine, but just doesnt work today.. sigh. how odd. 
I through my code maybe not right.

**I just want to make sure my expression is correct.** if there is no error with my expression then would be my code.

codes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
       $(window).bind("load", function () {
              var urlHash = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
                $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#' + urlHash).offset().top}, 1000);
    }); 
});
    </script>

<style type="text/css">
.space{height:800px;}
#anchor{font-size:25px;height:800px;display:block;}
</style>



<div class="space"></div>
<div id="anchor">This is anchor</a>
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Why does it have an error in the console? What error is it? Could it be that strings do not support a `hide` method?

Comment: And where is `idname` defined?

Comment: **OKAY YOU JUST EDITED IT....** - Now you have to give more details...

Comment: What is is the variable `idname`? Add `console.log(idname)` and what does it write out?

Comment: @epascarello updated all codes, thanks

Comment: Why are you binding `window.load` inside of `document.ready`?

Comment: Thanks @lan, got it to work after removing window.load....  I shouldn't use it inside of.

Comment: @olo Was that the actual solution to your problem?

Comment: I guess so. I removed it then it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with the error, the issue would be the fact that the hash is not being returned. So if there is no hash, you are looking for an element with $("#")

```
var urlHash = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#' + urlHash).offset().top},
```

the window.location has a hash property, so there is no reason to split

```
var urlHash = window.location.hash;
if (urlHash.length>1) {
    var elemPosition = $(urlHash).offset().top;
} else {
    elemPosition = 0;
}
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: elemPosition }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you missing the jQuery identifier ?

```
var id = 'my_dynamic_id';
$("#" + id).hide();
```